# Remove Characters from a Cell in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need to get only values after '=' sign i.e.

**Original:**

```
aad.eaadDetails = e-AD Details
```

**Result:**

```
e-AD Details
```

Please help me in dealing with it as their are 1000s of such values/data which needs to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter into cell `A1` the following string:

```
aad.eaadDetails = e-AD Details
```

Enter into cell `B1` the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND("=",A1))
```

**Output in B1:**

```
e-AD Details
```

Assuming you enter all your data into the `A` column, you can simply copy the formula in `B1` down all the way to achieve what you want.  Note that this formula extracts *everything* after the `=`, which may include whitespace.  I also assume that there is only one `=` sign in each string.